# How to configure a WhatsApp Share button for iOS and Android?

Tags: javascript, php, ios, objective-c, whatsapp

The problem is that Android and iOS have different schemes URL.

For [Android](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/ru/android/28000012):

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
```

For [iOS](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013) - **Objective-C**

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

I define the type of device as follows:

```
<?php
$iPod    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iPhone  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$iPad    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$Android = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
if( $iPod || $iPhone || $iPad ) {
    // ???
} else if( $Android ) {
   echo '<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>';
}
?>
```

Tell me how to use the code shown in the documentation Objective-C, if the site uses php and javascript (jquery)?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the normal link (the android version) does not work on iOS-Devices?